# Separate commands in a script block

Tags: powershell

Consider this simple code:

```
$myObject = New-Object PSCustomObject
$myObject | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'Multiply' -Value { $x=Read-Host; $x = $x * 10; Write-Host "$x" } 
$myObject.Multiply()
```

Entering `1` returns `1111111111` but I would expect the value to be `10`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because  `$x` is a *string* as you can verify by calling `$x.GetType()`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

You can fix that by casting the variable to a `[double]`:

```
$x=Read-Host; $x = [double]$x * 10; Write-Host "$x"
```